# SQL Join two tables connected by a third cross table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one table `bill`, and one table `log`. 
Each bill has one log. Therefore there is a third table `bill_log` with two columns bill_id and log_id.

I want to select all columns from bill and logs in one statement with

```
bill_log.bill_id=bill.id and  bill_log.log_id=log.id
```

I tried to join these tables, but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: please post what did you try and tag your sql engine you are using? and does each `bill_id`  unique to `log_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select bill.*,log.* from bill 
inner join bill_log on bill_log.bill_id=bill.id 
inner join log on bill_log.log_id=log.id
```